# How do I use gitattributes to prevent Git and Visual Studio from auto-merging a specific file?

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, merge

Each of our GIT repositories have a simple semantic version file, called "version". It's a file with the semantic version of the repository on a single line of text. We have CI/CD pipelines that bump this version file after each successful push. Unfortunately, this frequently creates merge conflicts on our local branches.

This wouldn't be an issue, but GIT is automatically overwriting the remote copy of the version file with our local versions. We use the "Commit All and Sync" option provided by visual studio. I believe this does the following under the covers:

Git Add -> Git Commit -> Git Pull -> Git Push

I added a line to the .gitattributes file in an attempt to set the merge driver to binary for that file. This is what it looks like now:

```
###############################################################################
# Set the merge driver for project and solution files
#
# Merging from the command prompt will add diff markers to the files if there
# are conflicts (Merging from VS is not affected by the settings below, in VS
# the diff markers are never inserted). Diff markers may cause the following 
# file extensions to fail to load in VS. An alternative would be to treat
# these files as binary and thus will always conflict and require user
# intervention with every merge. To do so, just uncomment the entries below
###############################################################################
#*.sln       merge=binary
#*.csproj    merge=binary
#*.vbproj    merge=binary
#*.vcxproj   merge=binary
#*.vcproj    merge=binary
#*.dbproj    merge=binary
#*.fsproj    merge=binary
#*.lsproj    merge=binary
#*.wixproj   merge=binary
#*.modelproj merge=binary
#*.sqlproj   merge=binary
#*.wwaproj   merge=binary
version     merge=binary
```

Based on the existing comment in the .gitattributes file, this should force the current user to manually resolve merge conflicts in this file. [Git's documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) also says something similar:

> Binary: Keep the version from your branch in the work tree, but leave the path in the conflicted state for the user to sort out.

The .gitattributes file and the version file are in the same directory. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The short answer is "you don't". The `.gitattributes` file only has partial control: it's not strong enough to prevent Git from merging the file even if it's marked binary. It's best to just not store such files in Git at all, which completely sidesteps the problem. That might not be an option here though.

Comment: I've griped about this before: Git should have a `.gitattributes` option that tells Git *use the merge driver even if you think you know the answer* and then one could write a correct merge driver (or use `binary` for this case for instance). But it isn't in Git.

Comment: @torek I see, perhaps we can use tags to version our repositories instead.